# Detect if Class has an element inside of certain Class?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get an Alert if a class contains an element of a certain class.

My attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/d9qecgjx/1/

HTML

```
<div class="parent">

  <div class = "child1">
  </div>
  
  <div class = "child2">
  </div>
  
  <div class = "child3">
  </div>
  
  <div class = "child4">
  </div>

</div>
```

jQuery

```
if ( $( ".parent" ).hasClass( ".child3" ) ){
                alert("You have that");
}
```

Comment: `if ($(".parent>.child1").length)`  or `if ($(".parent .child1").length)` if you don't want direct descendant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use .find() - it searches descendants. so

```
if ( $( ".parent" ).find( ".child3" ).length ){
                alert("You have that");
}
```